Detecting singular points from a parametrization
Suppose $r(t)$ parametrizes some, say algebraic, curve in the plane. It can certainly be that $r$ is smooth but the curve is not, since $r$ resolves double points by passing through them at different times. Still, if $Z(F(x,y))$ is a variety which contains this curve it will have to have vanishing gradient at the double point.
Going between the two representations (parametric vs. implicit) can be a difficult computational problem. Still, assuming one can do so, it must be that $r$ is somehow aware of the singular point. My question is whether there is a simple way to detect the double point from $r$?
For instance, assuming $F$ exists, the chain rule tells us that $\nabla F$ is orthogonal to $r'$, and so is proportional to $(-y'(t),x'(t))$, say $\nabla F=h(t)(-y'(t),x'(t))$, and the singular points (that aren't non-smooth points of $r$) are at the zeroes of $h$. But I don't see how to actually compute $h$, so it's not clear how to proceed. This all feels like 19'th century geometry, and I wouldn't be surprised if it's well-known.

Write $r(t) = (a(t),b(t))$.
A necessary condition for $r(t)$ to be a singular point of the image of $r$ is that either $r(t) = r(s)$ for some $s\neq t$ or $dr/dt =0$ at $t$. If neither happens and, wlog, $a(t)$ has nonzero derivative at $t$, then $c(t)$ has a local inverse $c(x)$ and the local equation $ y = b(c(x))$ for the image of $r$ shows this image is nonsingular at $r(t)$.
Both conditions can be detected using the resultant of $(a(t)-a(s))/(t-s) $ and $(b(t)-b(s))/(t-s)$ in the variable $s$ since the first condition is satisfied if and only if these polynomials have a common zero $s \neq t$ and the second condition is satisfied if and only if these polynomials have a common zero $s=t$ (since the value of $(a(t)-a(s))/(t-s)$ at $s=t$ is given by the derivative of $a$ by L'hopital's rule, and similarly with $b$.)
